# display message when trying to kick itsellf (the bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

i'm making responses in commands. I made a response when trying to kick myself and works, but now i'm trying to make a response when trying to kick the bot and it doesnt work.

kick command code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
 aliases: ["k"],
    description: "kick a member",
 execute(message, Discord, client) {
    if(message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")){
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let mention = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (message.mentions.members.size < 1) return message.reply('You must mention someone to kick them.').catch(console.error);
        if (message.mentions.members.first().id === message.author.id) return message.reply("I can't let you do that, self-harm is bad:facepalm:");

        if (message.mentions.members.id === client.member.id) return message.reply("You pleblord, how can you use a bot to kick itself?:joy:");

        if (message.mentions.members.first().id === "521311050193436682") return message.reply("You can't kick my Developer:wink:");
        if (reason.length < 1) reason = 'No reason supplied';

        if (!message.guild.member(user).kickable) return message.reply('I cannot kick that member');

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0x0000FF)
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField('Action:', 'Kick')
        .addField('User:', `${user.username}#${user.discriminator} (${user.id})`)
        .addField('Moderator:', `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
        .addField('Reason', reason)
        .setFooter(`© Cryptonix X Mod Bot by ${customisation.ownername}`);

            if(user.bot) return;
          message.mentions.users.first().send({embed}).catch(e =>{
          if(e) return;
          });
             message.guild.member(user).kick();

         let logchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name = 'logs');
            if  (!logchannel){
         message.channel.send({embed});
            }else{
         client.channels.cache.get(logchannel.id).send({embed});
          message.channel.send({embed});
         } 
            if(user.bot) return;
         message.mentions.users.first().send({embed}).catch(e =>{
            if(e) return ;
             });
         }

         else{
            let newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e4e265')
            .setTitle('')
            .setURL('')
            .setDescription("Eeeh wait! You can't use that command <a:yepaa:797528125894295567>")
            .setImage('')
            .setFooter('');
    
            message.channel.send(newEmbed).then(r => r.delete({ timeout: 10000 }));
            }    
     }
};
```

and this is the error i get when trying to run the command in discord chat

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of undefined
at Object.execute (C:\Users\ayman\Desktop\sharky music\commands\kick.js:15:56)
```

(kick.js:15:16 is the line of the bot response when trying to kick the bot)

Comment: The error is saying that `client` is undefined.  Are you sure that client parameter gets passed in to `execute` or did you just jam it into the function declaration and hope?  Maybe try changing `client.member.id` to `message.client.member.id`, since `message` definitely exists and the second tip [here](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) says that "message.client" is a way to access the client.

Comment: thanks i'll try it

Comment: hi. I did what you said but still didnt work, so i tryed to replace client.member.id to "is of the bot" and worked. But now i tried to kick someone and it tells me that reason is not defined, and i don´t know how to define it

Answer (score 0):

if you look closely you have defined member at
`const member = message.mentions.members.first();` and  `let mention = message.mentions.members.first();`

`!message.guild.member(user).kickable` after you have changed the user value from their code you missed to change the (user).kickable which returned member undefined as the bot cannot find the "user" not the "mention"

member and mention are all defined value in djs. so i would say change it to something like mentioned.

you can try to :
delete `const member = message.mentions.members.first();`

change to:

`const mentioned = message.mentions.members.first();`

`!message.guild.member(mentioned).kickable`

`if(mentioned.bot) return;`

`message.mentions.mentioned.first().send({embed}).catch(e =>{if(e) return;});`

and finally kick it by  `message.guild.member(mentioned).kick();`

didnt know it worked or not but hopefully afterall member is going to be defined!

---

think James might be answered as he have already posted in comments but i just leave what i think here. If im wrong, correct me.

Comment: hi. I did what you said but still didnt work, so i tryed to replace client.member.id to "is of the bot" and worked. Also, you told something of copying. My friend is the developerof Nezuko (+100k servers) and he helped me with the codes.

Comment: AH... thats ok then. i just wonders due to it was really similar to the one in link. if he helped you, then sure. i wouldve expected my code didnt work as expected due to i just changed the value around.

Comment: ok no problem, and also thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

> `if (message.mentions.members.id === client.member.id)`

This if condition is wrong because a property `member` doesn't exist on the [client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

You have 2 ways to fix your problem:

1. Replace `client.member.id` with `client.user.id` (The ids are the same)

   ```
   // The other code from above this if statement
   if (message.mentions.members.id === client.user.id) return message.reply("You pleblord, how can you use a bot to kick itself?:joy:");
   // The following code
   ```
2. Replace `client.member.id` with `message.guild.me.id` [me](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) is the Guild#GuildMember object from the client

   ```
   // The other code from above this if statement
   if (message.mentions.members.id === message.guild.me.id) return message.reply("You pleblord, how can you use a bot to kick itself?:joy:");
   // The following code
   ```